# DataTables warning - Incorrect column count

Tags: javascript, c#, html, html-table, datatable

I am coding in asp.net mvc and I am trying to implement the table of DataTables.net but I get this error:
[DataTables warning: table id=abc - Incorrect column count. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnGzE.png)

This is my table:

```
<table id="abc" class="display table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Program)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YearGraduate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BoardScore)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Program)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YearGraduate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BoardScore)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.StudentID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.StudentID }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.StudentID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: what does your datatable initialization in javascript look like, also you seem to miss <thead> and <tbody>

Comment: You can read the DataTables [installation guide](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML), which includes a section describing how to provide the HTML table structure required by DataTables.

Comment: This is also covered in the page mentioned in your error message: [Incorrect column count](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/18). Did you follow the resolution guidelines provided there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your table is incorrect you are missing <thead> and <tbody> tags.

this is a valid table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of  is not equal to the number of , this error can also be for this reason

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "If the number of is not equal to the number of". Right now it is unclear what you mean with the number of in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the command columnDefs.targets .

I remove this command, and the error solve

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and i realised i had two  in my tbody. So i think this error occurs either number of columns defined by the header and used in the body is not equal. Or you have some problem in the definition of table.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. You had two what in your tbody? The problem was that it missing the <thead> and <tbody> tags.

Comment: Sorry, i had two <thead> tags so that was causing this problem.